# $GL(n,\mathbb{K})$ as algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials

It' known that the set $V:=GL(n,\mathbb{K})\subseteq \mathbb{K}^{n^2}$ is an algebraic set of $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{K}^{n^2+1}$. How I can prove that V isn't an algebraic set of $\mathbb{A}_\mathbb{K}^{n^2}$?

Comment: Its complement is closed.

Comment: Are you asking for the non-existence of an open immersion of V into X := A^{n^2}, or just that the standard open immersion is not closed? Because the second follows from connectedness of X, and the first from an easy dimension argument.

Comment: @EstonianFootballerJoelLindpere He's probably asking why it's not a closed subset of $n^2$-space (doesn't algebraic set usually mean Zariski closed?). This also follows from a a simple dimension argument.

Comment: Oh sorry, where I wrote non-existence of an open immersion I actually meant closed immersion. Obviously there exists an open one.

Comment: @EstonianFootballerJoelLindpere There's not an open immersion into $n^2$-space either. Open subsets have the same dimension--closed subsets have at most the same dimension.

Comment: @AlexYoucis I'm confused. How is the open set in $n^2$-space given by requiring det $\neq 0$ not the same as GL(n)?

Comment: @EstonianFootballerJoelLindpere Oops, I must have been sleepy when I wrote that--my bad. A proof of the actual question is as follows. Suppose that $\text{GL}_n\hookrightarrow\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ is a closed embedding. Then, obviously, it must be an isomorphism for dimension reasons (and the fact that $\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$ is reduced). So, we really just need to verify that $\text{GL}_n\not\cong\mathbb{A}^{n^2}$. But, this is clear. For example, if we have an isomorphism $k[x_{i,j}]_{\det}\cong k[x_{i,j}]$ then $\det$ would go to a unit of $k[x_{i,j}]$

Comment: but these are just $k^\times$, but this is impossible since this is supposed to be an isomorphism of $k$-algebras, so the only elements mapping to $k$ are just $k$.

Comment: I'm new of Algebraic Geometry and in my course the concept of dimension isn' intruduced. Are there others proofs?